# Cppcheck with microsoft compiler extensions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cppcheck

The code below uses the microsoft compiler extensions `__try` and `__leave`:

```
void f()
{
  char* a = nullptr;
  __try {
    a = (char*) malloc(10);
    if(!a) __leave;
    a[1];
  } __finally {}
}
```

Currently the code above gives the following warning:

```
(warning) Either the condition '!a' is redundant or there is possible null pointer dereference: a.
```

So the problem seem to be that cppcheck does not understand that `__leave` leaves the block if a is null. Replacing it by a 'return' cause the warning to go away.

Is it possible to make cppcheck understand this? The cppcheck manual states:

> You can check non-standard code that includes various compiler extensions, inline assembly code, etc.

but I didn't find any further information about that.

Note, I am not looking for changing the code to make cppcheck happy but to make cppcheck understand the existing code.

Comment: The obvious solution is to invert the condition. Put the code under a positive branch `if(a) { a[1]; }`

Comment: @StoryTeller yuck. Early-outs for the win :)

Comment: @StoryTeller this is just an example though. I am more interested in how to get cppcheck to understand the `__leave` keyword in general.

Comment: @Quentin - I can always spin a tale of `goto leave_block;` instead. Wonder how cppcheck will react then :P

Comment: @Zitrax - I took a glance at the documentation of cppcheck. Couldn't find anything of substance that could help you, myself. Then again, the source is available, so you can modify it to do it.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best solution, but you might be able to work around this with "defining" `__leave` as `return`. Just give `-D__leave=return` to cppcheck.

Comment: @OriBS It will in general trigger other issues since `__leave` only leaves the current block and not the whole function. Imagine for example a call to free later in the function, cppcheck will now think you have a memory leak.

Comment: @OriBS Actually `-D__leave=break` works better and reasonably well on my code base. It's still not perfect though since I think it will still not handle the `__finally` blocks properly.

Comment: there was an upstream ticket filed for this - see https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/8434